# I m trying to get configuration file for google cloud messaging for IOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have successfully completed all the steps but when i m trying to get configuration file for cloud messaging , i m getting this error **"You submitted a bad request. Try again. "** What could be the reason ?

Comment: You need to provide more information and your code. Have you looked at this https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-status

Comment: getting the same error, but sadly only found just this question regarding this

Comment: Looks like this is known issue and Google is working on it https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/107